Can we stop re-render of child component if parent component is updating the state that we are using in child comp. in react?
Below is simple component of react.
Can we modify in any like using ref or anything so that child component won't re-render even if the state value changes from parent and still child component gets the latest value.
Again i'm just exploring the possibilities of react and how we use state in react.
i need a help to understand this. hope you all got my question clearly.
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  return (
      <div>
      {console.log("parent")}
        <h1>Parent Component</h1>
        <p>State: {state}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setState(state + 1)}>Increment State</button>
        <ChildComponent state={state} />
      </div>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = ({state}) => {
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child Component</h2>
      {console.log("child")}
      <p>State in Child: {state}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <ParentComponent />
);

export default App;


I have provided basic component that we use in daily basis in react.
i just want to have some modification in this component which helps in to stop re-render of child component.

and still child component gets the latest value. If you want the child to display the new value, that's what rendering is for. Don't stop the child from rendering.

This is not possible.
By default, when a component re-renders, React re-renders all of its children recursively.
If the reason of the parent rerender is a state change that is NOT consumed by a child component, you can avoid the rerender of the child by using memo (https://react.dev/reference/react/memo).
However if you pass the state of the parent to a child, you will always rerender the child-component when this state changes. That's the way React works.
In your example, if the state is not used by the parent, you should probably just define it in the Child.
